# Android TabLayout update tab's view

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a TabLayout in which I add tabs dynamically using `tabLayout.addTab(tab, i);`. When I add a new tab in a position which a fragment was already loaded, the fragment isn't updated.

For example, this occurs when I I add two tabs initially, which get loaded, then add another tab at position 1. The tab at position 1 does not get updated. What do I need to do to trigger an update (I assume a call to `getItem(int position)`) from the FragmentPagerAdapter?

I have tried using a listener and calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the FragmentPagerAdapter when I call `tabLayout.addTab(tab, i);`, but that doesn't fix the issue. I have also tried calling `invalidate` on the TabLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Call `tabLayout.removeAllTabs();` every time you want to add tabs. Then just add the tabs in the required order.

**Alternately** you can write `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);` where mViewPager is your viewpager. This is the definition of this method-

```
/**
     * Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the
     * current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this
     * limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.
     *
     * <p>This is offered as an optimization. If you know in advance the number
     * of pages you will need to support or have lazy-loading mechanisms in place
     * on your pages, tweaking this setting can have benefits in perceived smoothness
     * of paging animations and interaction. If you have a small number of pages (3-4)
     * that you can keep active all at once, less time will be spent in layout for
     * newly created view subtrees as the user pages back and forth.</p>
     *
     * <p>You should keep this limit low, especially if your pages have complex layouts.
     * This setting defaults to 1.</p>
     *
     * @param limit How many pages will be kept offscreen in an idle state.
     */
    public void setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit) {
        if (limit < DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Requested offscreen page limit " + limit + " too small; defaulting to " +
                    DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES);
            limit = DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES;
        }
        if (limit != mOffscreenPageLimit) {
            mOffscreenPageLimit = limit;
            populate();
        }
    }
```